# XPath 1.0, 1st node in subtree

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-1.0

So what I want to do is identify the 1st node in some subtree of a xml tree.

here's an example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <road>
    <households>
      <household>
        <occupants>
          <person name="jim"/>
          <person name="jon"/>
          <person name="julie"/>
          <person name="janet"/>
        </occupants>
      </household>
      <household>
        <occupants>
          <person name="brenda"/>
          <person name="bert"/>
          <person name="billy"/>
        </occupants>
      </household>
    </households>
  </road>
  <road>
    <households>
      <household>
        <occupants>
        </occupants>
      </household>
      <household>
        <occupants>
          <person name="arthur"/>
          <person name="aimy"/>
        </occupants>
      </household>
      <household>
        <occupants>
          <person name="harry"/>
          <person name="henry"/>
        </occupants>
      </household>
    </households>
  </road>
</root>
```

now I want the 1st person mentioned per road.

so lets have a go...

```
/root/road/households/household/occupants/person[1]/@name
```

that returns the 1st person per occupants node.

lets try

```
(/root/road/households/household/occupants/person)[1]/@name
```

that returns the 1st person in the whole tree

what I sort of want to do is?

```
/root/road/(households/household/occupants/person)[1]/@name
```

i.e. take the 1st person in the set of people in a road

but thats not valid xpath 1.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be what you’re after, using the descendant axis:

```
/root/road/descendant::person[1]/@name
```

Comment: ok...it works!...I don't like it...I think because if I had some other persons in another hierachy it would give me the wrong answer, but I'll take it...thanks v much

Comment: @MrDatKookerellaLtd you could add a predicate to `person` to restrict the match to only those from a particular hierarchy, using the `parent` or `ancestor` axes. For example something like `/root/road/descendant::person[ancestor::household][1]/@name` would only include those `person`s that are part of a `household`. It would depend on your actual data of course.

Comment: yep....I always have half a mind on extensibility of the source XML, so I don't like pattern matches that break if someone extends the input schema...I wont worry about it though